# Problemas al generar cookie en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
que tal amigos tengo el siguiente código en c# para generar una cookie
```

- aquí llamo para poder crear la cookie

  ```
   SessionHelper.AddUserToSession(model.Email,model.RememberMe);
  ```
- este es el codigo de mi clase sessionhelper

  ```
   public class SessionHelper
  {
      private static WebDBTContext db = new WebDBTContext();

      public static bool ExistUserInSession()
      {
          return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
      }

      public static void DestroyUserSession()
      {
          FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
      }

      public static int GetUser()
      {
          int user_id = 0;
          if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
          {
              FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).Ticket;
              if (ticket != null)
              {
                  user_id = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.UserData);
              }
          }

          return user_id;
      }

      public static void AddUserToSession(string id, bool persist)
      {
          var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie("UserWebDBT", persist);

          cookie.Name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
          cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

          var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

          var user = db.MtoUsuarios.Where(u => u.UserName.ToUpper() == id.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();

          var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                          ticket.Version,
                           ticket.Name,
                           ticket.IssueDate,
                           ticket.Expiration,
                           ticket.IsPersistent, Convert.ToString(user.MtoUsuarioId));

          cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

      }

      public static void ActualizarSession(MtoUsuario Usuario)
      {
          HttpContext.Current.Session["UsuarioId"] = Usuario.MtoUsuarioId;
          HttpContext.Current.Session["CorreoElectronico"] = Usuario.UserName;
          HttpContext.Current.Session["EmpresaId"] = Usuario.MtoCompaniaId;
          HttpContext.Current.Session["Rol_Id"] = Usuario.MtoUsuarioId;
          HttpContext.Current.Session["Nombres"] = Usuario.FullName;
      }

  }
  ```

  bien el problema esta en esta linea de código que no me deja pasar

  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

  y me muestra el siguiente error.

  [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.]
  WebDBT.Helpers.SessionHelper.AddUserToSession(String id, Boolean persist) in C:\Users\Mirobiano\Source\Repos\WebDBT\WebDBT\Helpers\SessionHelper.cs:58
  WebDBT.Controllers.<Login>d__13.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Mirobiano\Source\Repos\WebDBT\WebDBT\Controllers\AccountController.cs:103
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
  System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
  System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
  System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +125

  **Información de versión:** Versión de Microsoft .NET Framework:4.0.30319; Versión ASP.NET:4.7.3282.0

  podrian echarme una mano por favor, muchas gracias

Comment: tienes que hacer un debug en el metodo  e identificar cual es el objeto nulo.

Comment: Gracias por contestar el objeto null es en esta linea  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

Comment: asi es pero tienes. varios objetos, HttpContext.Current ,  Response,  Cookies cual de estos es nulo?